# Matching an arrow's ends with the x-axis R plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering how to to get the **left-most end** and the **right-most end** of my `arrows()` in my **plot** to EXACTLY match the **left-most end** and the **right-most end** of my **X-AXIS** lying beneath it (if possible, such that one can read the values (within rounding error) for two ends of the arrow off the X-Axis right below it)?

**Here is my R code** with no success:

```
ci <- c(0.09253967, 0.48434172)

plot(1, 1, ty="n" ,ann=F, yaxt="n", bty="n", xlim=c(ci[1], ci[2]), ylim=c(0, 1), xaxs="i")

arrows(ci[1], .01, ci[2], .01, code=3, lwd=2, angle = 90, length = .08 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One method:** control where `axis` places the ticks:

```
ci <- c(0.09253967, 0.48434172)
plot(1, 1, ty="n" ,ann=F, yaxt="n", bty="n", xlim=c(ci[1], ci[2]), ylim=c(0, .3), xaxt="n")
axis(side = 1, at = ci)
arrows(ci[1], .01, ci[2], .01, code=3, lwd=2, angle = 90, length = .08 )
```

... but the ticks are at not-pretty locations (though you can easily control this).

**Another method:** find what `axTicks` thinks would be the correct axis ticks for the current plot:

```
newx <- range(axTicks(side = 1))
newx
# [1] 0.1 0.4

# ... your plotting code ...
arrows(newx[1], 0.02, newx[2], 0.02, code=3, lwd=2, angle=90, length=.08)
```

Comment: You can use `round` to control the numbers *and* their accurate positions, such as `ci <- round(ci, 1)`; or you can use `sprintf` or `format` to control the precision of the displayed number (which might be minutely different than the actual position), and feed these modified-precision strings as `axis(..., labels=)`.

Comment: Try `mtext("hello", side = 1, line = 2)`. `axis` doesn't allow adding a label in the way of `xlab="xyz"`, and by using `xaxt="n"`, you're telling the drawing gnomes inside your system that you will handle all things related to displaying that axis. So `mtext` works.